# Mysql query execution of not 100% working

Tags: mysql

execution of this query is not 100% sure. sometimes run but it thorough errors

I am trying to get users available balance, formula is this

```
Total Income - (Total Expense + Total Investment)
```

This is my query

please let me know what's wrong I am doing, and how can I do this in a better manner.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
start transaction;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE txn(
    source_type varchar(20)  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    amount decimal(11,0) DEFAULT 0
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

alter table txn add key source_type (source_type);

insert into txn(amount,source_type)
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount,source_type FROM `mst_transaction`
JOIN mst_vendor on mst_vendor.vendor_id=mst_transaction.vendor_id 
JOIN mst_source_type on mst_source_type.source_type_id=mst_vendor.source_type_id
WHERE mst_transaction.`family_id`='XHYYYZZZ' and source_type <>'Withdraw'  GROUP by source_type;

select amount into @income from txn WHERE source_type='Income';
SELECT sum(amount) into @exp FROM txn WHERE source_type <> 'Income';
SELECT round(@income-@exp,2) as available_balance; 

commit
```

sometimes this query executes but most of the times show this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'start transaction; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE txn( source_type varchar(20) CHARAC' at line 2 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; start transaction; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE txn( source_type varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, amount decimal(11,0) DEFAULT 0 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci; alter table txn add key source_type (source_type); insert into txn(amount,source_type) SELECT SUM(amount) as amount,source_type FROM `mst_transaction` JOIN mst_vendor on mst_vendor.vendor_id=mst_transaction.vendor_id JOIN mst_source_type on mst_source_type.source_type_id=mst_vendor.source_type_id WHERE mst_transaction.`family_id`='FMLY21254787' and source_type <>'Withdraw' GROUP by source_type; select amount into @income from txn WHERE source_type='Income'; SELECT sum(amount) into @exp FROM txn WHERE source_type <> 'Income'; SELECT round(@income-@exp,2) as available_balance; commit;
```

Comment: Looks like this is a procedure body, and previous delimiter re-assigning lost.

Comment: I didn't get you